# Sprint Boot - Post a single string/enum to a REST service

Tags: rest, spring-boot, http-post, consumer

I'm trying to send a single string to a REST API via Spring Boot but I keep getting 400: Bad Request. I checked through postman that this json is accepted by the API:

```
{
    "currency": "USD"
}
```

I wrote the following piece of code to post to this service:

```
public Account createAccount(Currency currency)
{
        Account account = (Account) restTemplate.postForObject(url, currency.toString(), Account.class);
        return account;
}
```

Currency enum is given below:

```
public enum Currency 
{
    USD, EUR
}
```

I tried both by sending it as the enum and string value, none worked.

Comment: Can you also post controller code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a class that encapsulates the enum eg:

```
public class CreateAccountRequest {

  private final Currency currency;

  public CreateAccountRequest(Currency currency) {
    this.currency = currency; 
  }

  public Currency getCurrency() {

  }
}
```

Then when you do postForObject:

restTemplate.postForObject(url, createAccountRequest, Account.class);

Comment: I already have a DTO object Account, should I still need a separate class? Let me update my original post to include Account DTO.